# Extract all numbers after a character

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a string like ssfdfksakf +  232332

Text, plus sign then number of any length.

I want the easiest way to extract the number without the whitespace or anything.

Answer (score 2):

This finds the first digit, then returns the rest of the string:

```
=MID(A1,MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9},A1&"0123456789")),99)
```

If you require the result to be numeric, then precede with a double unary:

```
=--MID(A1,MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9},A1&"0123456789")),99)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should convert the result to a true number with a double unary (aka *double minus*) after extracting the number portion as a string.

```
=--MID(A2, FIND("+", A2&"+ ")+1, 255)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could grab anything after the plus sign and then trim it:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1, FIND("+", A1) + 1, 999))
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a copy and on that use Find & Select with Find what:

`*`

(there is a space after the asterisk) and Replace with: left blank.